# Electric potential energy of a system

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

When an electron is brought close to an proton I understand the math why energy drops and we have to provide energy to move the electron similar to a battery. Now I'm looking for a more conceptual answer. Why do we have to provide energy? Won't the proton attract the electron?

Comment: Who says we have to "provide energy?" Please explain what you mean by that phrase. If the mechanical energy is dropping, there are other things happening that you didn't include in your question.  State all your assumptions, please.

Answer (score 1):

An external force doesn't need to supply energy to bring an electron closer to a proton. The electric field does the work at the expense of electrostatic potential energy.

The gravity analogy is when an object is released from some height $h$ near the surface of the earth, gravity does work converting gravitational potential energy of $mgh$ to an equal amount of kinetic energy of $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ (in the absence of air friction).

Hope this helps.